# How do I know if my x and y is in my list of lists

Tags: python, list

```
boxes = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]
x,y = 2,2
if (x,y) in boxes:
    operation...
```

I don't know how to know if x,y is in the list boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
if [x, y] in boxes:
    operation...
```

This compares `[x, y]` to every list in boxes. But note that it *does not check if all the elements of `[x, y]` are present in a sublist*, so the sub list needs to be **exactly** equal to `[x, y]`

So [1, 2] != [2, 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
boxes = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]
expected = [2,2]

if expected in boxes:
   print("Do your operation")
```